# How to bzip2 multiple files into one single archive file

Tags: bzip2

I am reading an offline document of bzip2 and I am told that I can compress multiple files into one single archive using bzip2 like this:

```
bzip2 finalArchive.bz2 file1 file2 file2
```

But when I try this I get

> Can't open input file finalArchive.bz2: No such file or directory.

and I'm getting those 3 files compressed individually as file1.gz2 file2.gz2 and file3.gz2 and I also know that I could `cat` them into one single file but I want to be ab;e to do that using one single command.

I am able to do just that using zip:

```
zip finalArchive.zip file1 file2 file3
```

and I'm getting the expected `finalArchive.zip` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `bzip2` and `gzip` work on a single file.  When that file is compressed, the uncompressed version is removed.  When extracting, the opposite takes place.

To put multiple files into a `bzip2` archive, first use `tar` to get them into one file, then compress that one file. Or since `tar` is "zip aware" you can use the `-j` flag to use bzip2 compression when you create the tar archive all as one step.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no such thing as this command: `bzip2 finalArchive.bz2 file1 file2 file3`?

Answer (score 2):

The most common Unix compression utilities (`gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`) all operate on single files, and the standard way to make a multi-file archive is to combine them with `tar`.

You get the `Can't open input file finalArchive.bz2: No such file or directory.` error because `bzip2` thinks you want to compress a file called `finalArchive.bz2`, which of course doesn't exist.

To accomplish what you want, use this command:

```
tar -cjf finalArchive.tar.bz2 file1 file2 file3
```

where the `j` option tells `tar` to use `bzip2` to compress the `tar` archive. See the [relevant section in the `tar` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html) for more about this.

If you are using a very old version of `tar` without compression support, you would need do the compression step manually:

```
tar -cf - file1 file2 file3 | bzip2 -c > finalArchive.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 1):

Either bzip2 and gzip use file concatenation. That means `bzip2 files` will result in `files.bz2`.
It's possible to concatenate multiple files like:

```bash
bzip2 -c file1 > files.bz2
bzip2 -c file2 >> files.bz2
```

However this is almost the same of doing `cat file1 file2 > files`
You can check the uncompressed result of the concatenation to the `stdout` by using the `bzcat` command, e.g:
`bzcat files.bz2`

So the `files.bz2` will still being a single file at the end. To be clear on that, if you extract the `files.bz2` like:

```bash
bunzip files.bz2
```

The result will be just a single file named `files`, and it's content will be the concatenation of the `file1` and `file2`.

Multiple files need to be packed with the `tar` command like `tar -cvjf files.tbz file1 file2`
Where the `-j` here is equivalent wrapper flag from the `tar` command to add the bzip compression.

Answer (score -1):

Remove finalArchive.zip just input the list of files. Example screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: care to add why the -1?